# ExtJS 5.0.1 sort datastore

Tags: javascript, sorting, extjs

I have a combobox which populates a list of countries as defined below. However when I load the combobox the entries get populated based on their order in the database. I would like the combobox to load alphabetically. Can anybody assist on how I can sort my datastore?

**Store Definition**

```
Tool.model.Base.defineModel(
    'Country',
    [{name: 'name', type: 'string'},
    {name: 'code', type: 'string'},
    ],
    true
);
```

**Combobox Code**

```
{
xtype: 'combobox',
labelAlign: 'top',
fieldLabel: 'Country',
id: 'CountrySelectField',
name: 'country_id',
store: 'Country',
displayField: 'name',
valueField: 'id',
width: 300,
allowBlank:false,
}
```

Comment: Your "store definition" doesn't define a store. Please make a working example in [Sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a sorter to your store, either during definition:

```
sorters:[{
    property:'name',
    direction:'ASC'
}]
```

or at runtime:

```
store.sort({
    property:'name',
    direction:'ASC'
})
```

Comment: Hello Alexander, I've attempted to use the sorters as you have mentioned above (adding to the store) but I keep getting syntax errors. Are you able to apply it to my config above and I can give it a shot?

Answer (score 1):

```
var countries = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['country', 'code'],
    data : [
        {"country":"USA", "code":"USA"},
        {"country":"Belgium", "code":"BEL"},
        {"country":"Bosnia", "code":"BOS"},
        {"country":"Uruguay", "code":"URU"},
        {"country":"Denmark", "code":"DEN"},
        {"country":"Canada", "code":"CAN"}
        //...
    ],
    sorters:[{
    property:'country',
    direction:'ASC'
}]
});

Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Country',
    store: countries,
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'country',
    valueField: 'code',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1g69

Comment: May be you should add a little annotation to your code

Comment: I'm sorry if it seemed a bit dry code and just a fiddle, this is an example of the sorters in action just like Alexander posted. However this is using local data, in the end just try to add the sorter to your store itself. Does that give you the desired result Jukebox?

Comment: Thanks JeroenDR - I've been attempting to apply the sorters to my store however it always returns a syntax error. Would you know how to apply the sorters as you have it defined to my store above? My store is being populated via a database and not static local data.

Comment: What's the error? Are you sure you didn't miss any semicolon or brackets anywhere? Does your combobox populate correctly?